# bash- reading file from stdin and arguments

Tags: bash, stdin

So I have googled this and thought I found the answers, but it still doesnt work for me.

The program computes the average and median of rows and columns in a file of numbers...

Using the file name works:

```
./stats -columns test_file
```

Using cat does not work

```
cat test_file | ./stats -columns
```

I am not sure why it doesnt work

```
#file name was given 
if [[ $# -eq 2 ]]
  then
      fileName=$2
  #file name was not given
  elif [[ $# -eq 1 ]]
  then
      #file name comes from the user
      fileName=/dev/stdin
  #incorrect number of arguments
  else
      echo "Usage: stats {-rows|-cols} [file]" 1>&2
      exit 1
  fi
```

Comment: "doesnt work" how exactly? Does it kick your cat? Does it eat your lunch? Does it throw an error? How is `$fileName` used later in the script?

Comment: `$fileName` is only used later to check if the file is a valid file:
     `#check that file is readable
    if [[ ! -r "$fileName" ]]
     then
         echo "Cannot read file" 1>&2
         exit 1
     fi`

This is not a one liner, just how it prints here

Comment: It is not creating the correct input...  
using: `./stats -columns test_file`
I get the following result (which is correct):
Averages:
5       4       5       5       4
Medians:
6       4       4       7       5

When using: `cat test_file | ./stats -columns`
I get the following:
Averages:
5       0       0       0       0
Medians:
6       6       6       6       6

Comment: It must be used somewhere else to actually read the data. Where? How? I'm betting you have some other command that is sucking up all the standard input data (a common one is `ssh` but `cat`/`read` and many others can as well).

Comment: To read the data, i am using:
`while read  -a rows; do echo $rows; done < "${2:-/dev/stdin}"`

`done < "${2:-/dev/stdin}"` is what Im using to read the data from either stdin or via the file

Comment: Not using `$fileName` there is silly since you have it and it contains what you want but that's a different issue. You have that **literal** code? Where does that `echo` output to? How are you actually *using* the contents of the file with that? How large is your script? Can you just paste it all into the question?

Comment: @EtanReisner This may be it...  I use `read` twice when computing the columns...  Is there a way to read the file, then "reset" the file to read from the beginning again for later `read`s?  Although not sure why this would only be a problem using `cat test_file | ./stats -columns` and not the other format

Comment: Yeah, that's likely the problem. You can't do that with standard input, not with the shell I don't think. You *might* be able to duplicate the fd and read from each one once but it is a *much* better idea to fix your script to stop reading the data twice.

Comment: You cannot rewind a pipe, since that would require rerunning the piped program (in this case, `cat`). Had you *redirected* stdin (`< file`), you could, in theory, rewind stdin, but bash doesn't actually provide any way to use that API.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple program that accepts piped input:

```
#!/bin/sh

stdin(){
    while IFS= read -r i
    do   printf "%s" "$i"
    done

}

stdin
```

Test is as follows:

```
echo "This is piped output" | stdin
```

To put that into a script / utility similar to the one in the question you might do this:

```
#!/bin/sh

stdin(){
    while IFS= read -r i
    do   printf "%s" "$i"
    done

}
rowbool=0
colbool=0
for i in $@
do case "$i" in
    -rows) echo "rows set"
           rowbool=1
           shift
    ;;
    -cols) echo "cols set"
           colbool=1
           shift
    ;;
   esac

done

if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]
then
     fileName=$1
fi
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]]
then fileName=$(stdin)
fi

echo "$fileName"
```